# Parent div with two children. Always make one child fill the parent even when other child is not displayed?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div that holds two children. One of the children will not always be displayed. How do I make the other child div the fill the height of the parent without overflowing?

My first child that won't always be displayed has a fixed height. I tried making the second child a height of 100%, which works if the first child isn't displayed, but when it is the second child overflows.

Here's a fiddle of my issue:

```
.parent {
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.child1 {
    height: 30px;
    background: green;
}

.child2 {
    height: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4fdf8ksy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [flexbox layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes).

Just set the `.parent` element's `display` to [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) and add [`flex-direction: column`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction):

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/27s679yq/)

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.child1 {
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
}
.child2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vh` instead of `%`. It means the height should be `100%` view post device.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fdf8ksy/3/)

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
}
.child1 {
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  display: none;
}
.child2 {
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.parent {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.child1 {
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
}
.child2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).